# ajax request of registration bootstrap form doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, forms, request, registration

the register function inside file name `signup.php` capture values of fields with ajax send them to `register.php` then display a toast reply */

```js
// js code inside signup.php 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function register(){
  var name=$('#form2').val();
  var email=$('#form3').val();
  var password=$('#form4').val(); 
  var question=$('#question').val(); 
  var repsec=$('#form5').val();
  if((email!="")&&(password!="")&&(name!="")&&(repsec!="")&&(quest!="")) { 
    
 $.ajax({
   var data = $("#reg").serialize(); 
   url:'register.php',
   type:'POST', 
   data:data,
   success: function(data){
   if(data=='success'){
   toastr.clear(); toastr.success('user: '+name+' registred'); } else {toastr.clear(); toastr.error(email+' already exists') } } }); } }; </script>
```

```html
<!-- registration form-->
<form id="reg" method="post">
  <div class="md-form" style="top: 25px;">
    
    <i class="fa fa-user prefix" style="top: 15px;"></i>
 <input type="text" name="name" id="form2" class="form-control"> 
 <label for="form2">Your name</label> </div> <div class="md-form" style="top: 25px;">
  
 <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix" style="top: 14px;right: 500px;"></i>
 <input type="email" name="email" id="form3" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 30px;" required> <label for="form3">Your email</label> </div>
  
 <div class="md-form" style="top: 28px;">
 <i class="fa fa-lock prefix" style="top: 14px;"></i>
 
<input type="password" name="password" id="form4" class="form-control" required>
<label for="form4">Your password</label> </div> <i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="top: 14px;margin-top: 40px;font-size:1.6rem;"></i>
  
  <select name="quest" id="question" style="margin-top: -25;margin-left: 38px;width: 497px;">
<option>What is the name of my best childhood friend?</option> <option>What is the best place I have visited?</option> <option>What is the best gift I received?</option>
  </select>

 <div class="md-form" style="top: 25px;left:40;">
 <input type="password" name="repsec" id="form5" class="form-control" style="font-size: 1.4rem;font-weight: bold;color: #000;width: 480px;" required>

 <label for="form5">Answer of secret question </label> </div>
 <div class="text-xs-center">
 
 <button class="btn btn-indigo" onclick="register()" style="margin-top: 25px;" type="submit">Sign up</button> </div></form>
```

The problem while submitting form the page reload without ajax reply and without inserting the new user on the database. I included all bootstrap files(css & js) and jquery library correctly, I even coded a login form similar to `signup.php` in which the ajax request work with toast reply correctly 
i tried to add `preventDefault`, changing type of submit to `input type=button` then verifying PHP code,database parameters but I have never find solution for 3 weeks

//register.php code

[image: Register]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onclick="register()"`  , try using javascript to submit the form instead.

```
document.getElementById("reg").onsubmit = function() {register()};
```

And remove the `onclick="register()"` event from the submit button.

I usually do this with jquery, but if you don't use that, I think the above will work. I have not tested it.

Here is a way with Jquery:

```
$(function() {
// register user
    $("button.btn-indigo").click(function(){
    register();
});
```

Comment: i do that but while submitting the page still reload without reply toast and without adding new user

Comment: @barsawi13 This should work.. hmm.
Maybe your error is somewhere else then, sorry I haven't used toast.
This is basically what I suggested: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_dom

Comment: What happens if you add onsubmit="return false" to your form tag ?